# Configure git secondary repo

Tags: git, repository

For some reason `git log repo2/master..master -- .` doesn't work for me (`"fatal: bad revision 'repo2/master..master'"`, the same applies to `git checkout repo2/master -- .`). My config looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = ssh://me@domain.com/var/git/me/repo.git
[remote "repo2"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = ssh://me@domain.com/var/git/me/repo2.git
```

I have no problem running `git checkout origin/master -- .`, so the problem only applies to "repo2" for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't the fetch for repo2 be:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/repo2/*
```

Comment: Indeed. The recommended way for configuring remotes is using the `git remote add` command as it won't make silly copy&paste mistake like this.